# multiple graphs of each time series

Tags: r, plot, time-series

I have the following dataframe where each user has 288 observations:

```
                          User5   User8   User10
   2015-01-01 00:00:00    12.3    10.3     17.5
   2015-01-01 00:30:00    20.1    12.7     20.9
   2015-01-01 01:00:00    12.8     9.2     17.8
   2015-01-01 01:30:00    11.5     6.9     12.5
   2015-01-01 02:00:00    12.2     9.2      7.5
   2015-01-01 02:30:00    9.2     14.2      9.0
   ....................   ....    ....     ....
   2015-01-01 23:30:00    11.2    10.7     16.8
```

How can I make a graph with multiple graphs of each time series?

Comment: What does "multiple graphs" mean?

Comment: Try `ggplot` with `facet_wrap`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another option is to convert from wide to long format then plot everything in the same graph. Below is the code that use the `DF` posted by @G. Grothendieck

```
library(tidyverse)
library(scales)

# Convert Time from factor to Date/Time 
DF$Time <- as.POSIXct(DF$Time)

# Convert from wide to long format (`tidyr::gather`)
df_long <- DF %>% gather(key = "user", value = "value", -Time)

# Plot all together, color based on User
# We use pretty_breaks() from scales package for automatic Date/Time labeling
ggplot(df_long, aes(Time, value, group = user, color = user)) +
  geom_line() +
  scale_x_datetime(breaks = pretty_breaks()) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

Edit: to plot each user in a separated panel, use `facet_grid`

```
ggplot(df_long, aes(Time, value, group = user, color = user)) +
  geom_line() +
  scale_x_datetime(breaks = pretty_breaks()) +
  theme_bw() +
  facet_grid(user ~ .)
```

[image]

Comment: Tanks a lot , i want the second graphs :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the data frame `DF` in the Note at the end read it into a zoo object and then plot.  Assuming that "multiple graphs" means one panel per user, any of the following 3 options can be used.  If "mulitple graphs" means one panel with three lines in it, one per user, then add the `screen = 1` argument to the first two and `facet = NULL` to the third.

```
library(zoo)
z <- read.zoo(DF, tz = "")

# 1
plot(z)

# 2
library(lattice)
xyplot(z)

# 3
library(ggplot2)
autoplot(z)
```

### Note

```
Lines <- "
Time,User5,User8,User10
2015-01-01 00:00:00,12.3,10.3,17.5
2015-01-01 00:30:00,20.1,12.7,20.9
2015-01-01 01:00:00,12.8,9.2,17.8
2015-01-01 01:30:00,11.5,6.9,12.5
2015-01-01 02:00:00,12.2,9.2,7.5
2015-01-01 02:30:00,9.2,14.2,9
2015-01-01 23:30:00,11.2,10.7,16.8"
DF <- read.csv(text = Lines)
```