# How ro draw a multiline plot in R

Tags: r, dataframe, plot, line-plot

I have a dataframe with 6 features like this:

```
                X1   X2   X3   X4   X5   X6
Modern Dog     9.7 21.0 19.4  7.7 32.0 36.5
Golden Jackal  8.1 16.7 18.3  7.0 30.3 32.9
Chinese Wolf  13.5 27.3 26.8 10.6 41.9 48.1
Indian Wolf   11.5 24.3 24.5  9.3 40.0 44.6
Cuon          10.7 23.5 21.4  8.5 28.8 37.6
Dingo          9.6 22.6 21.1  8.3 34.4 43.1
```

I want to draw a line plot like this:

[image]

I'm trying this:

```
plot(df$X1, type = "o",col = "red", xlab = "Month", ylab = "Rain fall")

lines(c(df$X2, df$X3, df$X4, df$X5, df$X6), type = "o", col = "blue")
```

But it's only plotting a single variable. I'm sorry if this question is annoying, i'm totally new to R and i just don't know how to get this done.  I would really appreciate any help on this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you make your problem reproducible by sharing a sample of your data so others can help (please do not use `str()`, `head()` or screenshot)? You can use the [`reprex`](https://reprex.tidyverse.org/articles/articles/magic-reprex.html) and [`datapasta`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/datapasta/vignettes/how-to-datapasta.html) packages to assist you with that. See also [Help me Help you](https://speakerdeck.com/jennybc/reprex-help-me-help-you?slide=5) & [How to make a great R reproducible example?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269)

Comment: These might help https://stackoverflow.com/a/48871624/786542 & https://stackoverflow.com/a/52789737/786542

Comment: Thank you @Tung, my dataframe is posted in the question, is the whole dataframe, not a head() function

Comment: My line chart is not based on time, but on features. I want to reproduce the same line chart of the pic i added

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way would be to convert your dataset to a long format (e.g. by using the `gather` function in the `tidyr` package), and then plotting using the `group` aesthetic in `ggplot`.

I recreate your dataset, assuming your group variable is named "Group":

```
df <- read.table(text = "
Group                X1   X2   X3   X4   X5   X6
Modern_Dog     9.7 21.0 19.4  7.7 32.0 36.5
Golden_Jackal  8.1 16.7 18.3  7.0 30.3 32.9
Chinese_Wolf  13.5 27.3 26.8 10.6 41.9 48.1
Indian_Wolf   11.5 24.3 24.5  9.3 40.0 44.6
Cuon          10.7 23.5 21.4  8.5 28.8 37.6
Dingo          9.6 22.6 21.1  8.3 34.4 43.1 ",
  header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Then convert the dataset to long format and plot:

```
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)

df_long <- df %>% gather(X1:X6, key = "Month", value = "Rainfall")
ggplot(df_long, aes(x = Month, y = Rainfall, group = Group, shape = Group)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point() +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom")
```

[image]

See also the answers here: [Group data and plot multiple lines](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10349096/6455166).

Comment: Hi. Thank you very much for your answer!! This looks like what i need, but when i'm executing your code, i'm getting the following error: `object 'Group' not found`. Do you knopw how i can fix this?? Thanks again :)

Comment: I missed out a step: I assume your group variable is named `Group`. See my edit above.

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot, now i got it right!! Just one more question please. How could i display the plot with the features ordered in ascending order by the column X4?

Comment: This is a separate issue, and the comments section isn't designed for extended discussion. I would suggest you open a new question for this issue.

Comment: Ok. Could you add a little edit to your answer if not please? If not, thanks anyway, you really helped me already

Comment: You might want to refer to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/18413756/6455166

Comment: It's ok, i got it!! the correct way to go is using the `reorder` function when passing the x values to ggplot. Thanks a lot Weihuang Wong!! :)